# How to checkout using subversion and https

Tags: svn

I have just installed subversion and the repository is hosted on Assembla.

Normally when I use windows I just use tortoisesvn and it prompts me for a username and password.

When I try to checkout from the terminal I don't know how to manually specify the username and password and it just freezes when I try to checkout without them (can't ctrl-C the hell outa there).

Here is what I am trying:

```
svn co https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/comcal/trunk
```

When I was trying to copy the command line just then I got this:

> svn: Server sent unexpected return
>   value (502 Proxy Error) in response to
>   OPTIONS request for
>   'https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/comcal/trunk'

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can specify a username using

```
svn co --username your_name https://svn.server.com/repository/trunk
```

and the password should be prompted afterwards.

However, it's not necessary to specify the username, svn is going to prompt you anyway.

This and more information can be found either in the [documentation of svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) or using a simple command:

```
svn help checkout
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's not just my lack of skills, Assembla repositories are screwed at the moment http://twitter.com/#!/assembla

Comment: +1, however I'd like to point out that in my experience SVN will use username of the logged-in user if a username is not provided.

Comment: With svn 1.10.2 on Windows 10, when svn prompts for the username it does not allow you to enter it. With every key press the computer beeps at you.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn co --username <username> <url>
```

prompts for the password. So this would be less helpful in automation script.

One may try this:

```
svn co --username '<username>' --password '<password>' <url>
```

Single quotes('') are required here. The command execution without quotes gives this error (at least in my case it happened):

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL '<url>'
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```